# LISA (local indicators of spatial association) p values in R versus in Geoda

Tags: r, geoda, moran-index, spdep

When calculating LISA statistics in GeoDa versus using the localmoran() function in spdep, the I values are nearly the same, but the p values can be quite different.

I know the two programs calculate significance in different ways, but I'm not sure I can clearly explain how. Can someone suggest a good way to explain to a mixed audience (to those with advanced and those with basic statistical knowledge, and to someone like me who's kind of in the middle) why the two results are different?

As the significance results are so different, are there reasons to prefer one method of calculation over the other?

Is there a way to make the results from the two programs more similar?

Comment: Can you give us some numbers using some sample data sets?

Comment: Have you checked whether the calculation of p value actually rests on some sort of randomization-based approach? This could account for possible differences between programs (but should also entail differences [however small] between different runs of the same program).

Comment: Thanks for your further inquiries. First, on another site, one of respondents had this to say about R versus GeoDa: "R computes the analytical expectations and variances, and GeoDa (I think) shuffles all the data but the i'th observation, which is the one 
being tested. As the documentation mentions, p-values will vary between runs in GeoDa, as the seed for the random number generator used to shuffle the data cannot be fixed by the user, so each set of draws differs" -Roger Bivand, [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openspace-list/0gtc7-udxMc) What does this mean in plain English?

Comment: For an example- in Geoda, San Bernadino has a moran's I of .57, is categorized as high-high and is surrounded by high-high counties; it and all of its neighbors have significant p values. In the R version, San Bernadino is likewise given a moran's I of .57 and both is and is surrounded by high-high category counties. But in R, the p value is insignificant for San Bernadino and its neighbors to the south.

Comment: @user2905280 The text you asked about means that R computes estimated values and variances using the formulae while GeoDa does something akin to bootstraping. It randomly drops some observations and calculates the measures many times in order arrive at the estimates. When doing randomisation you ened to be able to set the seed for the RNG if you want your analysis to be reproducible. If GeoDa doesn't allow you to do that, your results will be slightly different every time you do the analysis.